# Break on words when all letters are inline-block spans

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a text and every letter is a `span` with `display: inline-block;`:

```html
<div>
  <span class="item">A</span>
  <span class="item">A</span>
  <span class="item">A</span>
  <span class="item">&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="item">A</span>
  <span class="item">B</span>
  <span class="item">C</span>
  <span class="item">&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="item">A</span>
  <span class="item">B</span>
  <span class="item">C</span>
  <span class="item">D</span>
  <span class="item">E</span>
  <span class="item">F</span>
  <span class="item">&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="item">A</span>
  <span class="item">B</span>
</div>
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 70px;
}
```

By default, if the screen is viewport is smaller it will break on any letter. I would like to break on spaces, but without removing the `inline-block` as I need it for something else

Comment: Could you wrap your letter groups in ```divs```?

Comment: *but without removing the inline-block as I need it for something else* --> for what? describe what you want to achieve, probably there is an easier way without all these complex code

Comment: @ajarrow tried this, didn’t work

Comment: @TemaniAfif I need the inline-block so I can do scale transitions

Comment: You would have to add ```display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap``` to the main ```div```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with the text inside `div` elements and the following CSS added:

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.text-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

Demo:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.text-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    <span class="item">A</span>
    <span class="item">A</span>
    <span class="item">A</span>
    <span class="item">&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    <span class="item">A</span>
    <span class="item">B</span>
    <span class="item">C</span>
    <span class="item">&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    <span class="item">A</span>
    <span class="item">B</span>
    <span class="item">C</span>
    <span class="item">D</span>
    <span class="item">E</span>
    <span class="item">F</span>
    <span class="item">&nbsp;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    <span class="item">A</span>
    <span class="item">B</span>
  </div>
</div>
```